Job step dependent on the availability of the database
I have a procedure that should be run just after databases are restored. For that, I want to make a job with 2 steps:

Checking the databases' status at time intervals
Procedure, triggering after Step 1 on success

For Step 1, I want to use this query to retrieve status:
SELECT msd.state_desc
FROM [master].[sys].[databases] msd

Checking for certain databases where state_desc is not equal to RESTORING. If this condition is met, the second step should trigger.
I was thinking about doing this in SSIS. Which blocks should I use for this check? Or is it better to use just T-SQL?
Searched the web for solutions, but without success.

Why not do the task as part of the RESTORE process? Why do you need an entirely different "scheduled" task to do the work?

I am reading some data from different server via linked server.

That doesn't answer the question. What's wrong with RESTORE DATABASE...; <Start Agent Job>; in the same batch?

I have found a solution in T-SQL.
DECLARE @Database_Count int

SELECT @Database_Count = COUNT(*)
FROM [master].[sys].[databases] msd
WHERE msd.name IN (
    'dbname1',
    'dbname2',
    'dbname3'
)
AND msd.state_desc <> N'ONLINE' 
    
IF @Database_Count > 0 BEGIN  
    THROW 53000, 'DB not ready',1;
END


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
